# Views and Fields help

Tags: 7, views

I have product images that I want to appear in a view. Easy enough.  At the same time I have 6 different product types.  So what I'm trying to do is create a view that is 6 columns across.  Each column is a different product type.  Then each product will fall into 1 of 6 categories.  Some columns will have 4 items, some 7. I cannot seem to do this with the "Grid" layout.  Which seems the best way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Table would probably be the way to go or making your own views handler/template if you don't actually want "table" markup, since you can exclude at a more global level if the field is empty, when you swap over to table you will see the settings that have "exclude" this row if empty. That is usually the way I accomplish this task.

Comment: Is your `product type` a taxonomy?

Comment: You can create individual views blocks for each product types you want and display them using [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) Module, This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add a taxonomy with 6 "product-types" terms, then add a term reference field in contentype, make "6 content pane views" displaying your contentype and filtering on term reference, and with panels module (or display suite) do a 6 column display with all fields that you require, each view will have it's own column, and you are done.

Comment: MacLean Fitzgerald, Please "up vote" my answer; thanks.